# Replace title that can be tracked by social media with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo

Ho do I replace `document.title` so social media (e.g. VK) will be read it by link with a hash-bang? Here is what I've tried to do in my `$.ajax()` call:

```
success: (function(_this) {
  return function(data) {
    _this.articles[id] = data;
    var desc = ((data.seo_description.length > 0) ? data.seo_description : data.description);
    document.title = data.title;
    $("meta[name='description']").attr("content", desc);
    return _this.setArticleData(data, full);
  };
```

They do change on my page dynamically, but with I patse my link to VK (e.g. `example.com/media/#open-full-178`) I see title and meta from `example.com/media/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about _escaped_fragment_ concept to achieve SEO for dynamic websites.

You can either use existing services like "prerender" or run your own phantomjs server to render javascript before serving the pages to search engines.